# undefined method ‘authenticate' in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie on Ruby on Rails application, I have already created CRUD but still stacked in `Login` & `Logout` functionality.

This is my Sessions_controller:

```
def new
end

def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:passkey])
    # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
  else
    # Create an error message.
  flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
end
```

This is my view: `new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :passkey%>
    <%= f.password_field :passkey, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my model:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }
  validates :passkey, :confirmation => true, :length => {:in => 6..20}
end
```

When I click Login button then showing this error:

> NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
> undefined method `authenticate' for `#User:0x0000000d5c65e0>`

How can I fix this error?

I'm using `ruby 1.9.7` `Rails 4.2.5` & `mysql2`

That would help me a lot, Please.

Comment: Please share your `User` model. It does not have `authenticate` method, as stated in the error message.

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa i have updated my post

Comment: Please also use meaningful titles for the questions to be best googlable, e. g. “undefined method ‘authenticate’” instead of generic “How to solve an error.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add

```
has_secure_password
```

to your User model. Make sure you add

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

to your gemfile.

add a field called "password_digest" with string in your User model.

That's it. Rails will handle User authentication for you like a charm and you will be able to use #authenticate method on your Model as well!

Edit:
you can check out this project at github - [Rails Project @ Github](https://github.com/praserocking/NE0N3W5)
I have implemented authentication using Rails on this. Checkout user.rb, gemfile and user_controller.rb.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm newbie on ruby on rails application

This answer is going to be out of context, but if you're new, I'd most definitely recommend using [`Devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) over rolling your own authentication.

You can see a [very good tutorial on how to use Devise here](https://gorails.com/episodes/user-authentication-with-devise).

--

In short, **Devise** handles all the back-end for authentication; it's built on top of [`warden`](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Overview) and gives you pre-rolled `sessions` & `registrations` controllers.

I recommend Devise to you because you're new.

Creating your own authentication, whilst relatively simple, takes a lot of experience to understand. It seems from your question that you're following a tutorial or whatever, and don't really appreciate the underlying principles governing the process of authenticating a user.

I may be wrong, but if you implement Devise, get it working, then you're able to make your own afterwards...

---

If you wanted to use `Devise`, you would do the following:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.3'

$ rails generate devise:install
$ rails generate devise User
$ rake  db:migrate
```

This will set up the default `controllers`, `routes` and `warden strategies` for Devise; it will add itself to your `Model` and *should* allow you to run your server and get the authentication working.

You'll want to use the [`devise helpers`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) to manage access to the different parts of your application:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :authenticate_user! #-> user has to "login" to access app
end
```

In your views, you can use `current_user`, `user_signed_in?` and a bunch of other helpers to provide user-centric functionality:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render partial "nav" if user_signed_in? %>
```

This is only my recommendation, it won't help you with your own implementation of your authentication. Of course, I'll delete the answer if inappropriate.

---

To fix the problem you have right now,

> undefined method `authenticate'

This means you don't have an `authenticate` instance method on your `User` model. You need the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def authenticate
      # do something
   end
end
```

One suspects you're trying to invoke [Warden's `authenticate!` method](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies#authenticate)

I don't have huge experience with Warden; you'll want to ensure you're calling the correct methods for it. Because it's rack middleware, all of the `warden` helpers are available through `env["warden"]`, so I suspect you'll be using something like:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def authenticate
     env["warden"].authenticate! ....
   end
end
```

Comment: Hi **Rich Peck** Thanks for nice answer but I'm tired apply this, I'm trying to another way

Answer (score 4):

If you use the devise gem then you should not use the `has_secure_password` method. You should use the `valid_password?` method.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems your `User` class is missing a `authenticate` method. You should implement that.

In case you want to use the built in Rails authentication you should add `has_secure_password validations: false` to your user model.

Ref: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html#method-i-authenticate

Comment: Hi @Bert Goethals I think you are right, but now showing `undefined local variable or method `password_digest' `

Comment: I'm writing an answer for you

Comment: Please write answer slowly & gradually I'm waiting for this